# Can't add to object, after reading it

Tags: java, object, arraylist, file-io

this is the created object, we add one element to it.

```
ArrayList <Apartma> poljeApartma = new ArrayList<Apartma>();
poljeApartma.add(new Apartma()); //size(1)
```

the output code:

```
try {
    ObjectOutputStream oos =new ObjectOutputStream (new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("apartman.ser")));
    oos.writeObject(poljeApartma);
    oos.flush();
    oos.close();
    } catch (Exception aaa) {
        System.out.println("Tezave "+aaa.toString()); 
    }
```

that's how i read it:

```
try {
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream (new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream("apartman.ser")));
    poljeApartma = (ArrayList<Apartma>) ois.readObject();
    } catch (Exception aaa) {
        System.out.println("Tezave "+aaa.toString()); 
    }
```

I can print it:

```
System.out.print(poljeApartma); //size(1)
//the correct version, even if relaunch the program, so that works.
```

But as soon as i try to add to the object after i got it out of the file it doesn't do anything.

```
poljeApartma.add(new Apartma()); //size(1)
```

I tried it with simple ArrayList and it worked. I'm doing something wrong here, or the rest of my code is garbage.

Comment: Please include a [complete, testable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your object has became read only. The JVM can not be sure that the object retrieved while reading the file is in fact a `List` containing `Integer`. It is sure it is a `List` but for the rest, nothing is certain.

Here is an equivalent of your code

```
List<Integer> i = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4);
Object o = i;
List<Integer> list = (List<Integer>) o;
System.out.println(list);
list.add(5); // Runtime Exception
```

The certainty here is that `list` is a `List<?>`, nothing else can be said about it. The type of its content is unknown and thus writing is not permitted as we do not know what to allow to write.

For example, the following compiles perfectly

```
List<Integer> i = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4);
Object o = i;
List<String> list = (List<String>) o;
System.out.println(list);
```

---

This is a perfect workaround. Create a new `ArrayList` object and feed it the casted object as parameter.

```
List<Integer> i = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4);
Object o = i;
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>((List)o);
list.add(5);
System.out.println(list); // [1,2,3,4,5]
```

---

### Your code

```
poljeApartma = new ArrayList<>((List)ois.readObject());
```